# moodle | initiate $course and using add_moduleinfo

Tags: moodle

Suppose, I'm on global page, (not in a course's page).

And I would like to make a new quiz.

I got the id of the course of which, I want to add into the quiz.

And I use add_moduleinfo.

I would like to know, how it is possible to initiate $course parameter, I need to call within add_moduleinfo.

P.S. will it add the relevant section? I've understood that it will, though it looks quite strange for me.

another thing,

I used add_moduleinfo like this:

```
$s=array( 'name' => 'אוטומציה', 'introeditor' => array ( 'text' => '', 'format' => '1', 'itemid' => 892971641, ), 'timeopen' => 0, 'timeclose' => 0, 'timelimit' => 0, 'overduehandling' => 'autosubmit', 'graceperiod' => 0, 'gradecat' => '1', 'gradepass' => NULL, 'grade' => 10, 'attempts' => '0', 'grademethod' => '1', 'questionsperpage' => '1', 'navmethod' => 'free', 'shuffleanswers' => '1', 'preferredbehaviour' => 'deferredfeedback', 'canredoquestions' => '0', 'attemptonlast' => '0', 'attemptimmediately' => '1', 'correctnessimmediately' => '1', 'marksimmediately' => '1', 'specificfeedbackimmediately' => '1', 'generalfeedbackimmediately' => '1', 'rightanswerimmediately' => '1', 'overallfeedbackimmediately' => '1', 'attemptopen' => '1', 'correctnessopen' => '1', 'marksopen' => '1', 'specificfeedbackopen' => '1', 'generalfeedbackopen' => '1', 'rightansweropen' => '1', 'overallfeedbackopen' => '1', 'attemptclosed' => '1', 'correctnessclosed' => '1', 'marksclosed' => '1', 'specificfeedbackclosed' => '1', 'generalfeedbackclosed' => '1', 'rightanswerclosed' => '1', 'overallfeedbackclosed' => '1', 'showuserpicture' => '0', 'decimalpoints' => '2', 'questiondecimalpoints' => '-1', 'showblocks' => '0', 'quizpassword' => '', 'subnet' => '', 'delay1' => 0, 'delay2' => 0, 'browsersecurity' => '-', 'boundary_repeats' => 4, 'feedbacktext' => array ( 0 => array ( 'text' => '', 'format' => '1', 'itemid' => '941466359', ), 1 => array ( 'text' => '', 'format' => '1', 'itemid' => '864816352', ), 2 => array ( 'text' => '', 'format' => '1', 'itemid' => '101278785', ), 3 => array ( 'text' => '', 'format' => '1', 'itemid' => '773833773', ), 4 => array ( 'text' => '', 'format' => '1', 'itemid' => 291053486, ), ), 'feedbackboundaries' => array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', ), 'visible' => '1', 'cmidnumber' => '', 'groupmode' => '0', 'groupingid' => '0', 'course' => 2, 'coursemodule' => 0, 'section' => 0, 'module' => 16, 'modulename' => 'quiz', 'instance' => 0, 'add' => 'quiz', 'update' => 0, 'return' => 0, 'sr' => 0, 'submitbutton2' => 'שמירת שינויים וחזרה לקורס', );

function tt($s,$t=null)

{

if(!$t)

$t=new stdClass();

//the problem is that the interior array wasn't convert into an object, so the sql gests mess with array syntax of php

foreach ($s as $key=>$value)

{

$z=$value;

if(is_array($z))

$z=tt($z);

$t->$key=$z;


}



return $t;

}



//var_dump(tt($s));

$newcm = new stdClass();

$newcm->id=2;

//to fix: making course an object, that fits modlib!!!

var_dump(add_moduleinfo(tt($s),$newcm));
```

and nothing was changed in the database, where am I wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try converting the interior array items into objects and see if that works. Also in the past, I have had to declare

```
global $COURSE;
```

at the beginning of the PHP file before I can access its contents like

```
$COURSE->id;
```

later in my program.